# why unsupervised model needs to implement nn.diag?

Tags: deep-learning, torch, unsupervised-learning

I am trying to learn deep learning.

In torch tutorial,

https://github.com/torch/tutorials/blob/master/2_supervised/2_model.lua

https://github.com/torch/tutorials/blob/master/3_unsupervised/2_models.lua

**Supervised model**

```
-- Simple 2-layer neural network, with tanh hidden units
model = nn.Sequential()
model:add(nn.Reshape(ninputs))
model:add(nn.Linear(ninputs,nhiddens))
model:add(nn.Tanh())
model:add(nn.Linear(nhiddens,noutputs))
```

**Unsupervised model**

```
-- encoder
encoder = nn.Sequential()
encoder:add(nn.Linear(inputSize,outputSize))
encoder:add(nn.Tanh())
encoder:add(nn.Diag(outputSize))
-- decoder
decoder = nn.Sequential()
decoder:add(nn.Linear(outputSize,inputSize))
-- complete model
module = unsup.AutoEncoder(encoder, decoder, params.beta)
```

why unsupervised model needs to implement nn.Diag ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should actually ask this on the [torch mailing group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/torch7). You're more likely to get an answer there. (I'm also curious about this issue, so please do post there)

Comment: OK~ Done
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/torch7/zRRpK9418qE

Comment: just scaling by some weight, maybe ...

Answer (score 0):

It is in fact a scaling by a learnable vector (the diagonal of a matrix). This is mentioned in the section 3.1 of the paper [Learning Fast Approximations of Sparse Coding](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/gregor-icml-10.pdf). It is multiplied by the tanh and together form the non linearity.